# What is the "Set Style" button for?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What is the Set Style button for in the TF2 backpack?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some hats and misc items have multiple styles to them.  `Set Style` switches between them.

I'll post a list of these items shortly, as well as a screenshot or two.

These items are:

Added 2011/04/14:

- Googly Gazer
- Ghastlier Gibus
- Scotsman's Stove Pipe
- Treasure Hat
- Hat of Undeniable Wealth And Respect

Added 2011/04/20:

- Grimme Hatte (I think)
- Pyromancer's Mask
- Troublemaker's Tossle Cap

Added 2011/05/05:

- Aperture Labs Hard Hat (formerly [classified])
- Blighted Beak

Some of these are different models, some of these are just different paint jobs.

Here is my Team Spirit colored Pyromancer's Mask with the paint changes:
[image: Pyromancer's Mask Original]
[image: Pyromancer's Mask Full Color]
[image: Pyromancer's Mask Stylish]

Here is my Ghastlier Gibus with model changes:
[image: Ghastlier Gibus]
[image: Ghastly Gibus]

Comment: And Ghastlierest Ghibus.